# Predict-style function: converting between strings and symbols

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a `predict` style function for lme4's `lmer` models. The idea is that the predict function will work on a dataframe containing factor and variable levels, of the kind produced by `expand.grid`:

```
level_df <- expand.grid(a=1:3, b=4:6)
```

I'm at the point where I can get the formula for calculating a given effect/interaction as a string:

```
formula_string <- "a * b + 3"
```

But the only way I've been able to apply that formula to the level dataframe (in this case, evaluating the formula for each value of `a` and `b`) is through some pretty liberal and probably dangerous use of things like `assign` and `eval`:

```
EffectFunction <- function(df_row, formula_string) {
  l_cols <- colnames(df_row)
  for (i in 1:ncol(df_row)) {
    assign(l_cols[i], df_row[1, i])
  }
  parsed <- parse(text=formula_string)
  df_row$effect_val <- eval(parsed)
  return(df_row)
}

pred_results <- adply(
  level_df,
  1,
  formula_string=formula_string,
  EffectFunction
)
```

Are there safer and faster ways to convert between strings and symbols/variable names?

Comment: Why the `for` loops, will `eval(parse(text = formula_string), level_df)` not work?

Comment: Ah, so you can use a data frame as an environment? That's exactly the kind of hint I was looking for, add it as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  a `data.frame`  as the envir argument for `eval`

so

```
 eval(parse(text = formula_string), envir = level_df)
```

should work nicely as it will look (first) within `level_df` for any variables.